# Select item from one list based on item in another list in the same order

Tags: c#, linq, select

`exhibits` contain ids that are in a certain order. When I query another table to get the `BMI` ids based on the `exhibit` ids, the order is not the same. Instead of pulling the first document id in `exhibit`, I think it is pulling the first record in the database that has the same `exhibit` id, but I want it to pull the record in the database in the same order as the `exhibits` ids.

```
var exhibits = _context.ApExhibits.Where(x => x.CASE_ID == apDockets.CASE_ID)
    .Where(x => x.EXHIBIT_NBR != null)
    .Where(x => !documents617.Contains(x.DOC_ID))
    .OrderBy(x => x.EXHIBIT_NBR)
    .Select(x => x.DIM_ID).ToList();

if (exhibits.Count > 0)
{
    var bmiIds =
        _context.DocumentImages.Where(x => exhibits.Contains((int)x.DIM_ID))
            .Select(x => (int)x.BMI_ID).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `.OrderBy(x => x.EXHIBIT_NBR).First()`  ? assumption it exists.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your first collection `exhibits` is ordered based on `EXHIBIT_NBR` whereas when you query the `_context.DocumentImages` you're not ordering it by the same property, hence you're going to receive results based on the order of the elements in the source sequence which in this case is `_context.DocumentImages`. Essentially, you're saying *"given an element of the source sequence `DocumentImages`, search linearly within the  `exhibits` collection and if there is an element which meets the given criteria then retain the element of the source sequence"*.

So let's say the first element from the source sequence `DocumentImages` to be passed into the `Where` clause has an equivalent `id` of an element from the collection `exhibits` but the element in `exhibits` is say at the `5th` position, this will make the element of the source sequence the first element of the result list when we perform a `ToList()` *eager* operation on the methods whereas it should technically be at the `5th` position of the result list given that the matching element from `exhibits` is also at the `5th` position.

So in order to have elements that are in the same order as `exhibits`, one solution is to *inner join* the `DocumentImages` and `exhibits` collections which would be the equivalent of checking if one element in one collection is contained within another. Then we can order by the same property as you did with `exhibits`.

example with query syntax:

```
var bmiIds = (from e in _context.ApExhibits
              join x in _context.DocumentImages on e.DIM_ID equals (int)x.DIM_ID
              where exhibits.Contains((int)x.DIM_ID)
              orderby e.EXHIBIT_NBR
              select (int)x.BMI_ID).ToList();
```

example with fluent syntax:

```
var bmiIds = _context.ApExhibits
                     .Join(_context.DocumentImages,
                          e => e.DIM_ID,
                          x => (int)x.DIM_ID,
                         (e, x) => new { e.EXHIBIT_NBR, x.BMI_ID })
                     .Where(x => exhibits.Contains((int)x.DIM_ID))
                     .OrderBy(e => e.EXHIBIT_NBR)
                     .Select(x => (int)x.BMI_ID).ToList();
```